# Firestore Insufficient Permissions

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I keep receiving this error:

```
Adding Post Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

These are my current permissions, which lets anyone do anything (which isn't ideal, but I'm just testing).

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Posts {
        allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

And the code I am trying to run is:

```
func addPost (postID: String, date: NSDate, link: String, profileID: String, text: String) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let settings = db.settings
    settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
    db.settings = settings
    db.collection("Posts").document(postID).setData(["Date": date, "Link": link, "ProfileID": profileID, "Text": text]) { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print ("Adding Post Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("Post added sucessfully")
        }
    }

}
```

Why am I getting this error message? I am running the latest version of `FirebaseFirestore` as of June 27, 2018.

Comment: try 


service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {allow read, write;
    match /Posts {
        allow read, write;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to specify that the user is allowed to access *documents* in the collection as shown in the [documentation on basic read/write rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Posts/{post} {
        allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Difference above is the `{post}` in `match /Posts/{post}`.